# Wont show result of calculation

Tags: python

i am very new to coding and stumbled upon my first problem I don't know how to solve:

```
weight_in_pounds=(input('How much pounds do you weigh? '))

weight_in_kilograms=weight_in_pounds*int(0.45)

print('You weigh '+ weight_in_kilograms +' kg.')
```

This is what I typed in and this is the result if I run it:

```
How much pounds do you weigh? 213
You weigh  kg.
```

I have no idea why it doesn't show the answer. For this example I typed in 213 but instead of the result it just shows a space. What did I do wrong?

Comment: **Hint**: `weight_in_pounds` is a `str`, not a number, and `int(0.45) == 0`. Try checking what the result of `"test" * 4` and `"test" * 0` are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With very minimal changes you can get it to work:

```py
weight_pound = int(input('How much do you weigh in pounds? '))
weight_kg = weight_pound*0.45
print('You weigh {0} kg.'.format(weight_kg))
```

The problem is as Brian mentioned. It's a matter of types.
Also you can only concatenate strings and so you'll have to use such formatting to get it to display.

> `*` `Repetition - Creates new strings, concatenating multiple copies of the same string`

[Explaination of operations on strings](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm)

You are repeating the same string zero times.

Answer (score 2):

You're converting 0.45 to an integer. 0.45 as an integer is 0. weight_in_pounds*0 = 0.

You're inputting weight_in_pounds, which makes it a string. Python is a bit weird with types, so a string * 0 is just an empty string.

You should first remove the conversion to an integer on the 2nd line and add a conversion to a float (decimal) to the first. I.E: `weight_in_pounds=float(input('How much pounds do you weigh? '))`